# rsync: Maximum nice to keep system responsive

Tags: performance, rsync, background-process, nice, ionice

Unfortunately a background `rsync` reduces the responsiveness of a server.

I search a way to have maximum niceness for this background task, to keep the server respond fast.

My current wrapper commands are this:

```
nice -n19 ionice -c3 nocache
```

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/159012/42348

Is there anything else which I can do to keep the backup rsync in background as much as possible?

One solution would be to use bandwith limitation, but I would like to avoid this. I want to apply this pattern to several servers, and it would be difficult to calculate the matching bandwith limitation for each server (since each server as different hardware and different network connections).